# hardware that be required to query a corpus of 40 million documents (15 TB) and 10 queries per second

Tags: 2013, search

I'm planning to implement Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise search.

What hardware that be required to query a corpus of 40 million documents (15 TB) and 10 queries per second? which topology I should apply form these :http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342836(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st i would check, if i have 40 Million items now or my assumption is in next 2 to 5 years i will cross the 40 Million items.

If **I have 40 Million Items** now, then i would go with large farm without any doubt because If you start with 40 millions their are chances in next 1 to 2 years you will add couple of millions more. In order to avoid the performance and enhancement of your Farm...it is better to go with Large farm. By the way we are in planning phase and selected the large farm(as we are planning for 70 Million items).

But If I assume that in next 2 to 5 years my document counts will be around 40 Million then i would go with Medium farm. Their are very good chances that in 3 to 5 years you will upgrade to new version of SharePoint.

Comment: thanks for quick response, can we decide what topology we need without know what is size of these documents? let's say I have 40 Million and the size is (15 TB) it is same as 40 Million with (30 TB)?

Comment: read technet for "item size limits" at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#Search you get the idea, Search dont care about the size rather its count number of items....Search downloads meta data and content from a document until it reaches the maximum document size. The rest of the content is not downloaded. Search always downloads a document's meta data.